# Create private voice channels and delete this channel when members in this channel 0

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

I wrote a code that if you go to a certain voice channel will create a new private voice channel, the problem is that after there is no one in the voice channel, it should be deleted, I wrote a code for this, but it does not work.

Here is the code itself:

```
@commands.Cog.listener()
async def on_voice_state_update(self, member, before, after):   
    cursor.execute(f'SELECT start_voice_channel FROM public."myBD" WHERE guild_id = \'{member.guild.id}\';')
    v_c = cursor.fetchone()
    voice_channel = v_c[0]
    
    cursor.execute(f'SELECT categori FROM public."myBD" WHERE guild_id = \'{member.guild.id}\';')
    c_c = cursor.fetchone()
    channel_category = c_c[0]

    if voice_channel is not None and channel_category is not None:
        print(f'\n First before: {before}\n')
        print(f'\n First after: {after}\n')
        print(f'\n Second before: {before.channel.id}\n')
        print(f'\n Second after: {after.channel.id}\n')
        if after.channel.id == voice_channel:
            maincategori = get(member.guild.categories, id = channel_category)
            channel2 = await member.guild.create_voice_channel(name = f'Privat({member.display_name})', category = maincategori)
            await channel2.set_permissions(member, connect = True, mute_members = True, move_members = True, manage_channels = True)
            await member.move_to(channel2)
            def check(self, x):
                return len(channel2.members) == 0
            await self.bot.wait_for('voice_channel_update', check = check)
            await channel2.delete()
    else: 
        pass
```

After I left the channel, it gives an error:

> if after.channel.id == voice_channel:
>
> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'

Just did a check here is what I got:

When I entered the channel:

```
First before: <VoiceState self_mute=False self_deaf=False self_stream=False channel=None>
Second after: <VoiceState self_mute=False self_deaf=False self_stream=False channel=<VoiceChannel id=751363819837718599 name='Voice Channel 1' position=0 bitrate=64000 user_limit=0 category_id=754670529268678669>>
Ignoring exception in on_voice_state_update
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 312, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "/app/cogs/commands/moderation/command/private_channel.py", line 43, in on_voice_state_update
print(f'\n Second before: {before.channel.id}\n')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

When came out:

```
First before: <VoiceState self_mute=False self_deaf=False self_stream=False channel=<VoiceChannel id=751363819837718599 name='Voice Channel 1' position=0 bitrate=64000 user_limit=0 category_id=754670529268678669>>
First after: <VoiceState self_mute=False self_deaf=False self_stream=False channel=None>
Second before: 751363819837718599
Ignoring exception in on_voice_state_update
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 312, in _run_event
await coro(*args, **kwargs)
File "/app/cogs/commands/moderation/command/private_channel.py", line 44, in on_voice_state_update
print(f'\n Second after: {after.channel.id}\n')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'
```

How can this be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

When deleting the channel, you must use `before.channel` instead of `after.channel` as if you use `after.channel` it gives you the NoneType error as if you delete a channel there can't be an after.

```
channel = discord.utils.get(guild.voice_channels, name=str(before.channel))
if channel is None:
    return
else:
    if len(channel.members) == 0:
        await channel.delete(reason=None)
```

Comment: Yes the problem is that when I go in the channel is created and everything is ok, but when I came out it gives this one about the window I wrote and I can't roll back from if `after.channel.id == voice_channel:` as it goes check if a specific channel is initial to create a private one